# binding SQL data to extract columns

Tags: asp.net, sql, data-binding, datatable, dataview

From my ASP.NET c# application, I want to run a SQL query and store all the column values so that I can use them in my application.

For example,

```
select name, age, phone, address, work from UserInfo
```

And I want to bind each of the columns (name, age, phone, address, work) into each individual textboxes in my page.

Is DataView the best way to do it?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: `DataView` etc. are the oldest .NET data technology. Look into Entity Framework.

Comment: thanks - i just had a look at it. Do you think I could use DataTables for this instead?

Comment: Again, that's the same ancient technology. You can use that, but why would you? It's a decade old.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can certainly use the [DataView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdcwwhez.aspx) to work with data on your .aspx page.

If it's "the best" way to do it depends on a lot of Things. Generally you probably won't see it used very much by more experienced ASP.NET developers, as you often end up with code where lots of business-like logic and data-access plumbing is put right in the .aspx.